# Event listener receives null detail if run after document loads

Tags: javascript, html, dom, google-chrome-extension

I've been working on an extension for Chrome.

In order to work, it must pass a global window variable set by the website to the extension's main script using a CustomEvent.
This usually works fine when the page is loaded in an active tab, but whenever it's loaded as a non-focused tab, or when the execution of the extension script is otherwise delayed, the event object received by the listener has a `null` detail attribute.

Just to be clear, the entire detail object of the event is `null`, not just the needed variable. I've made a workaround for this by attaching the needed variable to the document as a JSON string, but I'd like to understand what's wrong with the event.

Relevant parts of code are below.

manifest.json:

```
"content_scripts": [ {
          "js": [ "main.js", "jquery-3.3.1.js"],
          "matches": [ "*://*.site.com/*"],
          "run_at": "document_end"
       } ],
"permissions": [ "declarativeContent", "activeTab", "storage", "*://*.site.com/*" ],
"web_accessible_resources": [ "injectedScript.js" ]
```

main.js:

```
$(function() {

        document.addEventListener('globalPasser', function(response) {
            if(response.detail){
                // store variables
            }

        }, true);

        var passGlobals = document.createElement('script');
        passGlobals.src = chrome.extension.getURL('injectedScript.js');
        (document.head||document.documentElement).appendChild(passGlobals);
        passGlobals.onload = function() {
            passGlobals.remove();
        };
    }
```

injectedScript.js:

```
var newEvent = new CustomEvent('globalPasser', {detail:{variable: neededGlobalVariable}});
document.dispatchEvent(newEvent);
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice. 
The extension in question is https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/kinjamprove-continued/mcoeilbaljapapgpnokmhdgnmgdbimgo
It runs on any Kinja site (like avclub.com) with a comments section.

Comment: I can reproduce the bug since at least Chrome 30. I'll try to find the first bad version tomorrow. Meanwhile you can try 1) injecting the code via textContent on the script element; 2) passing the event via `window`, not `document`.

Comment: @wOxxOm I get the same results passing the event via window and injecting the code with textContent. I switched the content script to document_start, as well, but that seems to have made no difference, either.

Comment: https://crbug.com/917703

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The workaround/fix is to simply "sanitize" the data via JSON:

```
document.dispatchEvent(
  new CustomEvent('globalPasser',
    JSON.parse(JSON.stringify({
      detail: {
        variable: neededGlobalVariable
      }
    }))
  )
);
```

The problem in this case is caused by JS functions being present inside the data - sometimes - probably when the site still processes something. DOM nodes would have caused the same problem.

Intentionally or not, but Chrome aborts serializing the entire `detail` object and transfers it as `null` since https://crbug.com/85158 and this behavior weirdly differs from extension messaging, which skips such non-serializable stuff:  `{foo: functionRef, bar: 123}` is transferred as `{bar: 123}`.

Comment: I'm facing a [similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71540663/passing-a-promise-in-a-custom-event-detail) - but sanitizing the data using JSON does not seem to work on Promise objects, which just get modified to `{}`. Is there any workaround?

Comment: You'll need to resolve Promise first. Ask a new question if further assistance is required.