# Passing a promise in a Custom Event detail

Tags: javascript, promise, custom-events

I'm trying to pass a promise object via a Custom Event's `detail` property.
The custom event is passed between two scripts which are not sharing the same global context - one is an extension's content script and the other is the main website script.

`scriptA.js`

```
async function myFunc() {...}

document.addEventListener('eventA', function (event) {
    const outputEvent = new CustomEvent('eventB', { detail: { promise: myFunc() } });
    document.dispatchEvent(outputEvent);
});
```

`scriptB.js`

```
document.addEventListener('eventB', async function (event) {
    const { promise } = event.detail;
    const result = await promise;
    console.log('result', result);
});
```

Then I try to call this (either from `scriptB` or from a 3rd unrelated script, after both `scriptA` and `scriptB` were loaded):

```
document.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('eventA'));
```

When I print the `detail` object in `scriptA` before dispatching the event, it shows the promise object correctly, but it doesn't arrive to to `scriptB` at all - the `detail` property arrives as `null`.

Am I missing something here?

---

[When I create a sandbox to replicate it](https://codesandbox.io/s/angry-brook-20e2mn), it works fine.

However, in my actual code, it doesn't. here are screenshots from Chrome debugger:

In the dispatch part:
[image]
[image]

In the listener part:
[image]

If I don't include the `response` (which is a `Promise` object) in the dispatched `detail`, everything arrives correctly.

Comment: What do you mean by "different scripts" exactly? Please share a code example.

Comment: Which file dispaches `eventA`, and in what order are the files executed?

Comment: The code should work fine regardless of if they are in the same JavaScript file or not. The only difference is that an event might be fired before both scripts are fully loaded, in which case the event would be missed.

Comment: @AriSeyhun The event is not missed, it's arriving to the listener. The difference is that when I include the `promise` in the detail object (e.g `detail: {a: 1, b: 2, promise: ...}`, the `event.detail` arrives as `null` - otherwise the `{a: 1, b: 2}` object is arriving correctly.

Comment: Tried clearing your browser cache? Since it works in the sandbox, it could be just your local version is out-of-date

Comment: @Phil My local version is up to date, I verified it while debugging the source code in Chrome's debugger :)

Comment: Unfortunately, this is [not reproducible](https://jsfiddle.net/qrycw0vo/1/). There must be something unique to your application that you have missed from your question.

Comment: @Phil If I drop the Promise object from the detail or replace it with any other data type - it works perfectly. So I'm pretty sure this is the root cause of the issue. Maybe there's something unique to this promise object? I doubt it, but that's why I attached a screenshot of how the promise object looks exactly in the debugger. Is there anything else I can check about it?

Comment: I'm wary that you've simplified your code too much. The debugging screenshots show something quite different to the code in your question. You're going to have to show _actual_ code... where does `response` come from? If it's the result of a function, what **exactly** does that function do?

Comment: @Phil `response` comes from calling a function which is not mine. I am injecting a js script to webpage, and this script calls a function which is located on the `window` object of that page. So it gets a promise from this function, and tries to return it from that webpage to my main script (content script) through the event. If I `await` the promise in my injected script and return the response json, it works.

Comment: In the screenshots you've shown, the entire `detail` is `null`, so I doubt this has anything to do with `detail.response` being a promise.

Comment: Please show us the output of logging/inspecting `outputEvent` before you've dispatched it. If the event already doesn't contain the `detail`, we know that the `CustomEvent` constructor is to blame, otherwise it's `dispatchEvent`

Comment: @Bergi Added a screenshot, the output event construction is valid.
Regarding your previous comment - I don't know what else it can be - if I replace the promise object with a regular object / array / string - it works.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53898356/1380370) looks like the same issue.

Comment: The solution offered by @wOxxOm doesn't work on my promise object though, its value is changed to `{}` when sanitizing the data using JSON.

Comment: Have you compared your node version and CodeSandBox;s node version ? They might be different.

Comment: @amiregelz Their solution wouldn't work for you because a Promise is not serializable. You need to await the promise, and grab the data that you need and send that over the event detail. Otherwise, you could set a global variable to the value of the promise, and use that global variable in your event handler.

Answer (score 1):

First, thanks for the sandbox - it truly speeds things up and made it clear what you are currently facing

To the point

```
async function myFunc() {...}

document.addEventListener('eventA', function (event) {
    const outputEvent = new CustomEvent('eventB', { detail: { promise: myFunc() } });
    document.dispatchEvent(outputEvent);
});
```

I think that the problem is here

```
{ detail: { promise: myFunc() } }
```

Here you are attach the invokes promise.. why not assign the delegation only?

```
{ detail: { promise: myFunc } }
```

The meaning of this line is: assign the reference to my promise but son't invoke it (yet). It seems to be your original intention since youe later on used this code

```
document.addEventListener('eventB', async function (event) {
    const { promise } = event.detail;
    const result = await promise;
    console.log('result', result);
});
```

which supposed to be

```
const { promise } = event.detail; // promise here is the delegation to your function
const result = await promise(); // properly invoke it and wait for it's result
```

To my understating.. you can't invoke a promise in one code block and await result in another one. Hope that satisfy your original requirements

Comment: that's exactly the answer I would made. A quick look in the code and I've got the same point.

Comment: I edited my question with why it wouldn't work - the event is passed from/to an extension's content script, so I don't think it can access or pass a function from the main website context. Sorry for not including this detail originally.